# Women's fitness plan for weight (muscle?) gain

Tags: muscle, gym, weight-gain, aerobic

I searched on the internet for some women fitness plans for my girlfriend, a but lot of them are to lose weight. But she is slim, and I wanted some training for weight gain, and to strengthen her body.

Do you thing that I should look for some specific plans for the beginner (as she is)? Is it enough to start with any beginner plan for women? Or should I recommend an aerobic plan instead of the gym?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If she is trying to gain muscle, the most tried and true way is with lifting weights.  There are some things that [women do need to take into account](http://ironstrong.org/index.php?/forum/25-strength-training-for-women/) to set their expectations realistically:

- Lifting weights doesn't mean you start looking like a man--that's a unique set of bodybuilders, some of whom use steroids, and not what I'm talking about.
- Women don't progress as quickly as men do.  It's a physiological difference in the amount of testosterone--not anything you can do about that.
- Increasing strength will increase your muscle mass.
- You do need the support of other women who lift to work through your sticking points.
- The same plan that works for men can work for women

The community in the link I provided has a decent number of women lifters, and the group is 
very respectful.  Worth checking out.

A good starting program would be Starting Strength, or this newer spin on a beginner program also looks promissing: [The Average F'n Program](http://ironstrong.org/index.php?/topic/1157-the-average-fn-program-a-simple-and-efficient-training-template/).  Despite the name, it has a few good points to it:

- You have one lower body and one upper body lift each day: squat and overhead press, or deadlift and bench press.
- It's designed to keep your time in the gym no more than an hour long
- It's something that you can progress with for a good while.

Comment: Links are broken :(

Comment: I didn't realize it when I added the links, but you have to be a registered member of the IronStrong.org forum to see them.  They work, if you are logged in.

Comment: the Question still got views, so here is page with some interesting plans http://neilarey.com/, specialy I like the "30 days of change" or "90 days of action" programs :)